# Passing list-value to jQuery click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, arguments

I've got a litte js script which can change background images. You can address it by

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$("#test").click(function(){
   api.goTo(5); // this will call background slide no. 5
});
});
// this ahref will call the jQuery click handler and swap the background
<a href="javascript:;" id="test" name="test">Test</a>
```

And I need a way to tell the first script dynamically the page it has to swap to. The other script delivers a list structure this way:

```
<ul class="myclass" id="slider">
    <li jcarousel-page="1" class="active"><a href="javascript:void(0)"><span>1</span></a></li>
    <li jcarousel-page="2"><a href="javascript:void(0)"><span>2</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

What I finally try to get is, if you click on list item 2 for example, then the first script should be told "api.goTo(2)" to change to background 2...

I know there's an event handler function in jQuery. But I don't really get it how to pass by the number of the clicked list-item to the jQuery.click handler...

Thanks for helping!
Sebastian

Comment: I'm sorry, this is very difficult to understand. What is "the first script" and what is "the other script"? What criteria do you want to use to "dynamically" "swap to"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('li[jcarousel-page]').click(function() {
    api.goTo($(this).attr('jcarousel-page'));
});
```

Comment: this solution looks right the way i want it. i will try it tomorrow and leave you a feedback. thanks in advance!!